# How to pass >= condition filter to my year custom tax_query

Tags: pre-get-posts, tax-query

I have a custom taxonomy called year. I need to filter posts by pre_get_posts tax_query from year value to to year value. I am searching from one hour now feeling stuck. Please guide me.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to WordPress StackExchange! Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly. We need a reproducible and narrowly-scoped question. We need to know what exactly you've tried so far and where exactly you are stuck. For example would it be necessary to include your current query into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array of years to the tax_query (or use [PHP range()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)). The default operator is `IN` - see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_tax_query/__construct/#parameters

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
           'taxonomy' => 'year',
           'field' => 'name',
           'terms' => range($min_year, $max_year)
        )
     )
);
```